# Where to ask general performance related questions about web sites/apps?

Tags: discussion

Where would be a good place to ask general performance related questions about websites and webapps?

The Stack exchange communities Stack Overflow, Server Fault, Webmasters and Web Applications would be a possibility.

(What do I mean by "general"? E.g. discussing the [sitespeed.io web best practice](http://examples.sitespeed.io/4.2/2016-12-14-13-24-05/help.html) suggestions list)

Comment: Sounds like an opinion based party. I doubt any site in the network would be happy with those.

Comment: @rene do you have any alternative community suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: Web Apps is for _users_ of web applications, so I don't see how questions about performance could be on-topic there.

Comment: I normally suggest Quora.com or Reddit, or if you like chatting you could try a chatroom on the network here. Not all are open for that kind of stuff. Expect many cat gifs